# Android NDK/JNI: loadLibrary failure with dependant shared libarires

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, unsatisfiedlinkerror

In my project I am required to load three different shared libraries in which the third (the main one) depends on the first two. For the sake of simplicity the first two shall be named A & B whilst the third C.

Libraries A and B are large libraries that do not interact through JNI at all and are simply ports of existing libraries to android.

I have set up such a system without issue by setting my third library's android.mk as such:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := C
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <source files>

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/libA/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/libB/
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := A
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += B
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When loading this library through java I've used:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("C");
}
```

to much success.

This system works on my device as well as on all except one of my beta testers who received a UnsatisfiedLinkError in their stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInitializerError
  at <source>:<line>
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1892]: 1909 could not load needed library 'libA.so' for 'libC.so' (load_library[1094]: Library 'libA.so' not found)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
  at <source>:<line>
...
```

Changing my code to:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("A");
    System.loadLibrary("B");
    System.loadLibrary("C");
}
```

seems to fix the problem for that tester.

The tester with the issue used a Samsung Galaxy SIII with android 4.1.2 (supported by my native code) running on armeabi-v7a (same as my device).

Given that the single "load C" works for everyone but that one tester, is it a problem with the tester's device or is the "correct" way to do it to load all three libraries explicitly? And why would it have only failed for that one device.

LogCat for a single "load C" vs loading all explicitly:

```
07-26 23:23:29.333: D/App(13753): Loading core...
07-26 23:23:29.333: D/dalvikvm(13753): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-2/libC.so 0x41bfd598
07-26 23:23:29.333: D/dalvikvm(13753): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-2/libC.so 0x41bfd598
07-26 23:23:29.338: D/App(13753): Core loaded.
```

vs loading all:

```
07-26 23:17:50.193: D/App(12714): Loading core...
07-26 23:17:50.198: D/dalvikvm(12714): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libA.so 0x41bfaf20
07-26 23:17:50.198: D/dalvikvm(12714): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libA.so 0x41bfaf20
07-26 23:17:50.203: D/dalvikvm(12714): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libA.so 0x41bfaf20, skipping init
07-26 23:17:50.208: D/dalvikvm(12714): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libB.so 0x41bfaf20
07-26 23:17:50.208: D/dalvikvm(12714): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libB.so 0x41bfaf20
07-26 23:17:50.208: D/dalvikvm(12714): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libB.so 0x41bfaf20, skipping init
07-26 23:17:50.208: D/dalvikvm(12714): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libC.so 0x41bfaf20
07-26 23:17:50.208: D/dalvikvm(12714): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar.app-1/libC.so 0x41bfaf20
07-26 23:17:50.208: D/App(12714): Core loaded.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, loading explicitly A, B, and C is the correct way to work in Android. An alternative is to use *[crazy linker](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/ndk/sources/android/crazy_linker/README.TXT)*, which is supported since NDK r9.

In any case, it is important to choose special names for the libraries you use in your project, so that no system library is used by chance. E.g. Android devices have `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` in `/system/lib`, but many apps need more up-to-date versions of these.

**UPDATE**: crazy linker was [removed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/919573fac20b718ff89f140cc61c7ed941a0eac6) from NDK, but it can be found [in chromium project](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/third_party/android_crazy_linker) ([latest change: June 2017](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/938998bd58a2fabb04556833a298f3c7facd5135/third_party/android_crazy_linker)).

Comment: Any reason why loading the single "C" library worked for all devices apart from that specific one?

Comment: I cannot tell. I don't know which devices you tested, and the true names of your libs.